# Jasper Report Cross Tab Adding Parameter

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am having problem inserting a parameter into the top left hand corner of my jasper report cross tab. I need some "text" at the top left hand corner (seems strange), and although i am quite sure this is not easy or even legal, i would like to check if anyone has attempted something a similar feat.

[image: Parameter not found]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a crosstab variable (a measure) whose value is equal to the value of the parameter. Add the representative crosstab measure to the crosstab, rather than the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Add crosstab header, which you can find in the crosstab layout structure. By default it will be not applied so you have to add it.
Then you can add static/text fields, whatever you want at the top left corner in that, and you can properly adjust those elements using free layout property of the crosstab header.